# How to change toolbaritem color with out changing title color

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i need to change toolbaritem icon color with out changing the title color.

is their anyway to do that without having Custom view for navigationbar?

Comment: The ToolbarItem Icon is a picture, just change the picture i guess.

Comment: @JanWidmer Nope, i have colored picture now